# The same database name different server in same domain possible?

Tags: database, oracle, name

In Oracle world - is it possible to have the same database name in a different server in the same domain?  In our test environment the database server is cloned (VMWare) and then our DBA have to reconfigure and change the database name because he said insist it is not possible to have the same database name in a different server in the same domain.

I've experience in MS-SQL server and it's possible to have the same database name in different servers in the same domain so I just need clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by Domain. Oracle neither knows nor cares about Windows domains.
However there is a [DB_DOMAIN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/initparams044.htm) database parameter used for networked databases

And there are various ways for clients [to connect to Oracle databases (or at least finding out where the database is to connect to)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/network.920/a96580/namingcf.htm#505367) which could also impact database naming.

It can also impact OEM/Grid Control, backing up etc.

And at the simplest level, it is good to be able to determine, from within the database, what database you are in. So most places will have separate names for Prod, Dev and test databases (even or especially if they have been copied from the same source).

So while it may be possible to have multiple, identically names databases on different servers, the DBA probably has good reasons not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Used to work in a shop where they did nothing but that: Every oracle production server had 'numbered' databases: PR01, PR02, PR03 etc. etc.
You just identify the database by the SID + servername, thus PR01@big_iron is another database than PR01@small_iron.

Keep your tnsnames.ora in order, and you're set!